# How to exit more than 1 for loop in Excel VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, vbscript

The code is like:

```
'first for loop
for I = 1 to 5 
    do sth
    'second for loop
    for j = 2 to 7
        do sth
        'third for loop
        for m = 2 to 43
            if [condition] then 
               exit 2nd and 3rd loop and continue on next I ?????
            end if
        next
    next
next
```

I wrote two `Exit For`, but it did not help. It only exited the 3rd for loop and continue on next j.

Comment: Can you please post more complete code? I need to see where and how you entered `Exit For` to know what may be the issue.

Comment: Thank you. Please see my answer below. I believe this is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you nest a flag in your loops you can put an if statement prior to looping on your second loop. If the flag is true, then you exit the second loop as well.

```
'first for loop
for I = 1 to 5 
    do sth
    'second for loop
    for j = 2 to 7
        do sth
        'third for loop
        for m = 2 to 43
            if [condition] then 
               flg = True
               Exit for
            end if
        next
    If flg = True then Exit For
    next
next
```

Comment: Is the 'do' loop here obligatory?

Comment: There is no do loop here @Todd. I guess I'm not sure what the `Do sth` actually means, but I'm assuming it's shorthand for  `do something`, as what it actually does is somewhat irrelevant to the question from the OP.

Answer (score 3):

Make dummy `Do...Loop` inclusion:

```
' first for loop
For i = 1 To 5
    ' do sth
    ' dummy do loop, won't repeat, just creating a block to exit from
    Do
        ' second for loop
        For j = 2 To 7
            ' do sth
            ' third for loop
            For m = 2 To 43
                If [Condition] Then
                   ' exit 2nd and 3rd loop and continue on next i
                   Exit Do
                End If
            Next
        Next
    Loop Until True ' never repeats
    ' continue within 1st for loop
Next
```

Answer (score 2):

```
    For a = 1 To maxRows
        If Exam1Grade(a) > 99 Then
        For b = 1 To maxRows
            If Exam2Grade(b) > 99 Then
            For c = 1 To maxRows
                If Exam3Grade(c) >= 100 Then
                    MsgBox ("Stop looking through the 3rd exam, you have just found the perfect score")
                    GoTo ThisPoint 'Exit All For Loops
                ElseIf c = maxRows Then 'Restart At A
                    GoTo NextA
                End If
            Next c
            End If
        Next b
        End If
NextA:
    Next a
ThisPoint:
```

The GoTo statement can act as a break